# .net add item from listbox to another project in the same solution

Tags: .net, winforms, listbox, controls

I'm developping a .NET 4 project with more than one projects.
The principal project is a Windows Application within a listbox.
In the same solutions I have a Class Library project.

In the code behind in my windows form, I call a function in my class library.

Can I pass my listbox control from my project to my another project in the same solution and add to it items?

thank you

Answer (score 0):

Indeed you can.

But first add a reference to System.Windows.Controls in your Class Library.
Then you can have a public method on one of your classes

```
public void DoSomethingToMyListBox(ListBox list)
{
   list.Clear(); //or whatever
}
```

However. I would ask you to think about what it is you want to do with this listbox, and why you would need to pass it into another module - generally speaking that's a sign of a flaw in your design.

If for example you want to pass it in because you want to fill it with some items that are coming from a database, and you want to isolate the main Forms project from the database access (a good thing) then you should have your Class Library returning `data` and you should use the Windows Forms DataBinding components instead.

e.g

```
//on your Form's code
public Form1()
{
   var myThing =new MyClass(); //whatever the class in the class library is called
   var theData = MyClass.GetData(); //GetData returns List<something>
   MyListBox.DataSource=theData;
//if "something" is a class, use the two lines below
 //if something is just a list of strings for example, you don't need to bother
   MyListBox.DisplayMember="name of property on something to display in the list";
   MyListBox.ValueMember="name of property on something to use as list index";

}
```

Of course I don't know if this is what you want to do :)